# Can not receive promise in Blazor

Tags: promise, interop, blazor

I am doing a `POST` request from `Blazor` to a server via js interop.The post request gets to the server, is computed, is sent back. The `js` handler calls `resolve` for the promise, but the data does not get back to `Blazor`.

**JS Interop**

```
window.methods={
    submit: function () {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var form = document.getElementById("newTestForm");
                var data = new FormData(form);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


                var method = form.getAttribute('method');
                var action = form.getAttribute('action');
                xhr.open(method, action);
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        resolve(xhr.response); //data gets here in correct format !!!!!!!
                    }
                    else if (xhr.status != 200) {
                        reject("Failed to submit form with status" + xhr.status);
                    }
                }
                xhr.send(data);
            });
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/myroute")]
public async Task<string> ReturnData()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "hello";
}
```

**Blazor Component**

```
<form method="post" action="/myroute">
....some inputs
</form>
<button onclick="@SubmitAsync"></button>
@functions{
      public static async Task<string> SubmitNewTestAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var data = await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>("methods.submit");

                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

     public async Task SubmitAsync()
     {
         string data= await SubmitNewTestAsync();
     }
}
```

The response is correct, and the js method `submit` calls `resolve` on the result. I first thought it could be a deserialization problem. But it does not throw any error.

I have tried with different types of response ( `bytes`,`objects`,`string`) and there is still no response nor exception.

What could the problem be?

**P.S**  I need to use the `XMLHttpRequest` since I want to stay on the same page. I should see exceptions if they exist in Blazor since I am testing using `Server-Side hosting`

**Update**
Ok so after trying many things the problem seems to be on the `Blazor` side specifically in the `JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<Type>` method.
It seems the request will just **finish** without returning something (nor does it throw any error ) unless `Type` is `primitive`/`object`/`dynamic.`
I do not now if this is a `Blazor` specific problem anymore.

**Example**

Considering the following model:

```
[Serializeable]
public class MyType{
 public int value{get;set;}
}
```

So this is what happens (Blazor side):

```
var data = await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<MyType>("methods.submit"); //fails
var data = await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<object>("methods.submit"); //works
var data = await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<dynamic>("methods.submit"); //works
```

So far tested also with `long`,`int` and `string` and they work.
It seems there is no problem in receiving primitives.

Comment: I want to get its content.And i have used promises since it is an asynchronous operation on the webpage.Sincei am `await`-ing i do not need the `Task` but its result.

Comment: Indeed,this is what i was trying.`string data = await ....`

Comment: Does this fail: var data = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("methods.submit");

Comment: This does not fail.All primitives work including `string`.

Comment: If so, why do you fail to accept my answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be the result of using the static JSRuntime.Current property which has been removed. Instead, you should inject the IJSRuntime into your component thus:

**@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;**

```
public static async Task<string> SubmitNewTestAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var data = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("methods.submit");

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Try this code snippet in your JavaScript function:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(xhr.responseText);
      } else {
         reject("Failed to submit form with status" + xhr.status);
      }
    };
```

Comment: I have tried with this too.Still i do not get the results , nor do i get back with the debugger and still no exception is thrown.

Comment: Is xhr.response populated with data ?

Comment: Yes it is . I have checked with the browser debugger.It works great until `resolve(data)` at which point in blazor console it says `request finished successfully`.

Comment: I have updated my question.Thanks for your response.

Comment: Because it didn't actually solve the problem.I have found a workaround but i still can't send any custom type to blazor

Comment: What custom type you want to send to Blazor ? This was not your initial question. Post a new question indicating the custom type you want to pass to Blazor, and I'll try to solve your problem.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian - I am trying to do the same thing - Could you post your workaround as and Answer please? - Have you seen this blog post: https://joonasw.net/view/csharp-await-and-js-promises-in-blazor

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue with Stripe payment promise. [Call .NET methods from JavaScript functions in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1) looked like is good way to implement it. Then i found [Blazor Javascript Interoperability](https://toddlittlejohn.com/2019/09/15/blazor-javascript-interoperability/) blog post which solved problem briliantly.

Here are just some guidelines please fallow article to understand concept.

Javascript

```
function WithPromise(promiseHandler) {
   var somePromise =  promise.then((value) => {
   promiseHandler.invokeMethodAsync('SetResult', JSON.stringify(value));    
}
```

Promise handler

```
public class PromiseHandler : IPromiseHandler
{   
    public TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs { get; set; }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void SetResult(string json)
    {
        // Set the results in the TaskCompletionSource
        tcs.SetResult(json);
    }
}
```

Calling some function from c#

```
public Task<string> SomePromiseCall()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var promiseHandler = DotNetObjectReference.Create<PromiseHandler>(new PromiseHandler() { tcs = tcs });
    _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("WithPromise", promiseHandler);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```